# Count HTTP only cookies with Mozilla add-on

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I'm trying develop a Firefox add-on. I would like to count the cookies that are marked as HTTP only. When manually checking, I have seen that many websites have more than one HTTP only cookie. But, my result is always `0` or `1`. Where is my fault?

Here is my code:

```js
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var cookieManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsICookieManager2);
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('load', function(tab) { 
    var URL = tab.url;
    var url = require("sdk/url").URL(URL);
    var host = url.host;

    function getCookies(host){
        var cookies = cookieManager.getCookiesFromHost(host);
        var count = 0;
        while (cookies.hasMoreElements()){
            var cookie = cookies.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsICookie2);
            //var count = 0;
            var httpCookie = cookie.isHttpOnly;
            if(httpCookie){
                return count=count+1 ;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
            console.log("Cookie host: " + cookie.host + "; Cookie Name :" +  cookie.name 
                        + " = Cookie value:" + cookie.value + "\n");
            dump("\tCookie host: " + cookie.host + " Is Domain cookie: " +cookie.isDomain 
                 + "; Cookie Name :" + cookie.name +" = Cookie value:" + cookie.value 
                 + "; Is Session Cookie  :" + cookie.isSession 
                 + "; Expiry time  :" + cookie.expiry 
                 + "; It is an Http only cookie :" + cookie.isHttpOnly  +  "\n");
        }
        return count;
    }
    var getResult = getCookies(host);
    console.log("Http Cookies: " + getResult);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `function getCookies(host)` you have a `while` loop that is intended to loop through all cookies for the specified `host`.  However, the inner portion of that loop is only executed once.

Within that loop you have an `if` statement:

```
var httpCookie = cookie.isHttpOnly;
if(httpCookie){
    return count=count+1 ;
}else{
    return 0;
}
```

This statement results in the function immediately returning either a `1` or a `0` depending on if the first cookie found has the property `cookie.isHttpOnly` as `true` or `false`. [Note: `cookie` is always `0` when this `if` statement is executed for the first and only time.] No other cookies are checked other than the first one because you immediately `return` the value. Execution of your function ends at either of the two `return` statements within this `if` statement. The lines within the function after the `if` will not be executed.

From what you describe you desire, your `if` statement would be better as:

```
if(cookie.isHttpOnly){
    count++;
}
```

Note: Given that you only use `cookie.isHttpOnly` once, there is no need to assign it to a separate variable.

Comment: thank you  very very much, your help and explanation was perfect. Thank you for your time!! :)